# ImportError: cannot import name 'BigQueryOperator'

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I create the dag for my local airflow to create table and load the data from another table from cloud composer project using bigqueryOperator.
Here is the error

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\hsaini\airflow-local\dags\bigQueryOperator.py", line 4, in <module> from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryOperator ImportError: cannot import name 'BigQueryOperator' from 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery' (C:\Users\hsaini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\airflow\providers\google\cloud\operators\bigquery.py)`

i installed the package "pip install apache-airflow-providers-google" and "pip install 'apache-airflow[google]'".

here is my code

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow import models

from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryOperator
# from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigqueryOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta



# Define default_args
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 4, 20),
   
}

# Create a DAG instance

with DAG(
    dag_id = "dag_bigquery",
    default_args= default_args,
   # schedule_interval='@daily',
    catchup = False

) as dag :
    
    # create empty table task
    create_table_task = BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='create_table',
        sql="CREATE TABLE 'project_name.dataset_name.himani-dummy-table' "
            "(Brand_Id INT, Brand_Code STRING, Brand_Name STRING, Entity_Id STRING)",
        bigquery_conn_id='my-bigquery-connection',  
       
    )

    
    # load data in created table task
    load_data_task = BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='load_data',
        sql="INSERT INTO 'project_name.dataset_name.himani-dummy-table' (Brand_Id, Brand_Code, Brand_Name, Entity_Id)"
         "VALUES 'SELECT * FROM project_name.dataset_name.table_name LIMIT 10' ",
        bigquery_conn_id='my-bigquery-connection',
       
    )




create_table_task >> load_data_task
```

Comment: Try upgrading module
pip install --upgrade apache-airflow-providers-google

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be using some old syntax for BigQuery operators and that's what's throwing the error. The logic for BigQuery operations is now split into multiple operators - more info about those operators and what they can do can be found in the [BigQueryOperator documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/bigquery.html)

Regarding the code snippet you shared, for your create table task, I think you want to be using the `BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator`, and for your load data task, I think you'll be looking at the `BigQueryInsertJobOperator` or the `BigQueryInsertJobAsyncOperator`.